# Send http status 303 (See Other) in ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, post-redirect-get

How can i issue an [http status code of 303 `See other`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) in ASP?

Using:

```
<%Response.Redirect "http://stackoverflow.com"%>
```

issues a 302 `Object moved` to the client:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
Location: http://stackoverflow.com
```

[which isn't what i'm trying to do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

How can i issue an http status code of 303 (**See Other**) in ASP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<%
Response.Status = "303 See Other"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://stackoverflow.com"
Response.End
%>
```

Comment: i wouldn't have believed it if i hadn't seen it - i didn't know the `Status` was both `StatusCode` and `StatusDescription`.